# CSS template not loading in jsPsych

Tags: css, jspsych

I have written a simple script in jsPsych that welcomes the user to the page, then thanks them for their participation after they press any key. However, it does not load the CSS styling associated with the page. The style sheet is at the appropriate location, and there are no errors or warnings generated.

The entirety of the code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
><html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsPsych/jspsych.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsPsych/plugins/jspsych-html-keyboard-response.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsPsych/plugins/jspsych-image-keyboard-response.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsPsych/plugins/jspsych-survey-text.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="jsPsych/css/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>

  <script>

    var timeline = []

    var welcome = {type: "html-keyboard-response",
           stimulus: "Welcome to the experiment, and thank you for your time! Press any key to continue."
          };
    timeline.push(welcome)
    
    jsPsych.init({
    timeline: timeline,
    on_finish: function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/experiment-data",
        data: jsPsych.data.get().json(),
        contentType: "application/json"
        })
        .done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!")
            window.location.href = "/";
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("A problem occurred while writing to the database. Please contact the researcher for more information.")
            window.location.href = "/";
        })
    }
    })

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Think it has anything to do with the stay > symbol in the second line of your HTML?                                                 ```><html lang="en">```

Comment: @Uuuuuumm Thank, that is it.

Comment: Question: Why did everything else work, then? I would have expected it to mess up something else in the script, as well.

Comment: No Idea. HTML is kinda special.